# What's the best place to create Guice injection when handling GET with a servlet?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

Injector has to be created at some point. Currently I put in into static ctor of my servlet. But somehow it looks fishy. Furthermore I am calling `getInstance` directly from `goGet` to create all sort of classes. That may not be too bad but there are some limitations that I have to work around. So is there a better way?

Comment: Have you looked at https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets? Then you can just `@Inject` directly in your servlet.

Comment: No, I didn't. Thanks... Feel dumb now :) Could you convert your comment to the answer so that I could marked it as one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the [Guice Servlet](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Servlets) extension. You can `@Inject` your Guice managed classes directly into your servlets, filter your requests, and also gain access to useful scopes like `@RequestScoped` and `@SessionScoped`.